# Найти в строке из целых и дробных чисел числа 1 и 0 с помощью регулярных выражений python

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Необходимо с помощью регулярных выражений python вывести ['1', '1', '1', '0'], а у меня получается только ['1 ', '1 ', '1 ', '0 ']. То есть надо вывести без пробелов после цифр 1 и 0. Как сделать ['1', '1', '1', '0']

```
import re 
s='0.3 1.32 1 -6 1 6 0.77 1 2 0.4 0 0.356 0.32 0.7'
po = re.findall(r'[0-1]\s',s)
print(po)
```

Результат такого поиска: `['1 ', '1 ', '1 ', '0 ']`, а надо вывести `['1', '1', '1', '0']` без пробелов после цифр 1 и 0. Как это реализовать с помощью регулярных выражений python

Comment: `\b[0-1]\b` - добавьте границы слов вместо пробела

Comment: `[01](?=\s)` так?

Comment: @splash58 тогда выведет вместе с границами, вместо пробела. Вопрос то не в самом поиске, а в том что пробел попадает в соответствие.

Comment: граница - это элемент нулевой длины, его сложно вывести. Нет?

Comment: а да, проверил. туплю

Comment: `0.7` вот это только тоже подходит под условие

Comment: @splash58 Да что-то `.` тоже похоже считается "границей слова"

Comment: разумно, значит, надо заглядывать

Comment: Ещё `([0-1])\s` делает нужное, но это неправильно, боюсь - в конце строки требуется пробел, иначе последний элемент не обработается, если он будет подходить. Вы вообще задачу бы озвучили - интересуют строго одиночные `1` и `0`?

Comment: \b[0-1](?!\.)\b - https://regex101.com/r/Vw84gI/1

Comment: po = re.findall(r'\s([01])\s',' '+s+' ')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложу вариант с негативным просмотром назад и вперед:

```
(?<![.\d])[01](?![.\d])
```

Смотрим что перед 0 или 1 нет символов цифры или точки.
Так же проверяем что после не идет точки или цифры.
Пример:
[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/KuIZPj/1)

**UPD**: так же если возможны отрицательные значения и их захватывать не нужно, то стоит использовать в негативном просмотре назад появление минуса: `(?<![.\d-])`

---

Так же разберем варианты предложенные в комментариях
Вариант [@splash58](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/180637/splash58):

```
\b[0-1]\b
```

`\b` - граница слова, а точка как раз является границей, т.е. из **0.1** будет выбран и **0** и **1**

Вариант [@teran](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/223826/teran):

```
[01](?=\s)
```

Используется позитивный просмотр вперед на проверку пробельного символа `\s`, из строки "**0.1 0**" вернется **1**

Вариант 2 от [@splash58](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/180637/splash58):

```
\b[0-1](?!\.)\b
```

Тут уже используется негативный просмотр вперед с проверкой на отсутствие точки и установлены границы слова, но так же из **0.1** будет захвачена цифра **1**

Вариант от [@Виктора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/325344/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80)

```
re.findall(r'\s([01])\s',' '+s+' ')
```

Тут используется добавление пробелов в начале и конце строки. В самом регулярном выражение пробелы - захватываемые символы, а данные получаем из 1-й группы, и проблема в том, что при поступлении строки "**1 0 1**" под захват попадут только **1** и **1**. И вот почему:
В строку добавляются пробелы

```txt
 1 0 1
^^^ - первый захват
  ^^^ - захвата не будет, так как пробел уже в первом захвате
    ^^^ - второй захват, так как предыдущего захвата не было и пробел свободен
```

Comment: ну такой вариант чем плох? po = re.findall(r'\s([01])\s',' '+s+' ')

Comment: @Виктор добавил в ответ

Comment: Хорошо, тогда так  po = re.findall(r'(?<=\s)([01])\s',' '+s+' ')

Comment: @Виктор, если вы считаете что ваше решение более подходящее или более проще, то просто разместите его как ответ. В текущем виде при наличии позитивного просмотра назад не вижу проблем с возвратом результата. *но я не "последняя инстанция" так что ошибиться могу ;-)*